# Stdout from pipe with sleep

Tags: bash

I would like to capture the output of turbostat to a variable.  turbostat will run every 5sec by default so the man recommended to add sleep 1 on the end to just capture a single shot.  However when I do this I can not seem to pipe the result plus it writes the output to console unless I pipe everything to null.

How can I capture the output?

I tired this but to no avail.

```
CPUPower=$((turbostat --quiet --show PkgWatt --cpu package sleep 1 | pcregrep -o1 "PkgWatt[\r\n]+([^\r\n]+)") > /dev/null 2>&1)
```

Comment: You're piping the output to `pcregrep` and it's redirecting its output to `/dev/null`. How do you expect to get any output from that to the variable?

Comment: If the command substitution is writing output to the console, it must be writing to either `stderr` or `/dev/tty`, not `stdout`.

Comment: I thought that maybe putting the turbostat commands in brackets would evaluate that 1st before sending everything to null?

Comment: No, redirections work from the outside in, because a subshell inherits the I/O redirections from the parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [man page](https://www.mankier.com/8/turbostat), when `turbostat` is given a command to run, it sends its own output to `stderr`, not `stdout`. This is presumably so that the statistics can be distinguished from the output of the command.

So you need to redirect `stderr` to `stdout` in order to process it with `pcregrep`. You're doing this with the output of `pcregrep` itself, not the output of `turbostat`.

```
CPUPower=$(turbostat --quiet --show PkgWatt --cpu package sleep 1 2>&1 | pcregrep -o1 "PkgWatt[\r\n]+([^\r\n]+)")
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, I have to change the regex as the output is different that running the command normally but not a problem